# Проблемы с сертификацией SSL\TLS в C#

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient, tls, httpwebrequest

На серваке произошли проблемы с сертификатом. Мне нужно переписать программу по взятию файла с этого сервера так, что бы она игнорировала ошибки сертификации.
Я выделил основной проблемный код в отдельный консольный проект.
Вот он:

```
string path = Path.GetTempPath() + "1.pdf";
DownloadFileWebClient(new Uri("http://192.nnn.n.nnn/upload/documents/1.pdf"), path);

public static void DownloadFileWebClient(Uri requestUri, string path)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter");
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(sslPolicyErrors);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
        return true;
    };

    try
    {
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.DownloadFile(requestUri, path);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Exit");
}
```

Вот что выводит мне консоль при запуске:

```
Enter
----------------------------------------------------
RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
----------------------------------------------------
Exit
```

При этом код отрабатывает нормально и файл успешно скачивается.
**А теперь собственно моя проблема**:
Если скомпилированный код этой программы перетащить на сервер, где должно крутиться мое приложение, запустить, то вывод в консоль будет следующим:

```
Enter

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. at  
System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName) at  
Test.Program.DownloadFileWebClient (Uri requestUri, String path) in C:\Users\nnnn\Documents Projects Test Program.cs:line 36

Exit
```

Почему то делегат, который переопределяет колбек проверки сертификата вообще не вызывается?
**Собственно, у меня вопрос к знающим людям**: в чем может быть причина того, что при перемещении скомпилированной программы во втором случае вызова делегата ServerCertificateValidationCallback  вобще не происходит?
Проблема в коде, или в самой машине, куда я перекидываю код? Моя машина и серверная находятся в одном домене, правда у серверной нет доступа в интернет, но машина с хранением файла точно доступна для нее.

UPD1:
Если поменять WebClient на HttpClient то ничего не меняется. Фреймворк 4.7.2, на серваке стоит Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Дополнительную информацию пишите прямо в посте, его можно редактировать, а комментарий удалите. Версия винды какая? Брандмауэр на серваке проверьте. И зачем вам SSL в локальной сети? Работайте по HTTP. Кстати, у вас ссылка в коде и так `http://`. При чем тут SSL?

Comment: `вызова делегата ServerCertificateValidationCallback вобще не происходит` потому что чтобы произошел вызов, надо чтобы TLS соединение было успешно установлено для рукопожатия, а у вас оно валится раньше.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, апдейт добавил в пост. Сейчас по порядку. Эта ссылка приходит мне внутри json, я ей не управляю. Сервером я то же не управляю, это не мой а нашего заказчика. Мне сказали "почему твоя программа отваливается". Везде пишут что добавление этого кода решает ошибку с SSL, у меня с компа работает, на серваке нет. если поменять http на https ничего в поведении не поменяется, если заменить 192.nnn.n.nn на внешнее имя на которое выдан сертификат *.mosk***.ru то же ничего не происходит. Если идти по 192.nnn то просто происходит редирект судя по всему.

Comment: Версия винды на клиенте какая? Смысл в том, чтобы и сервер и клиент поддерживали TLS 1.2. 2008 сервак по умолчнию не поддерживает, но можно прикрутить. То же самое с клиентской виндой, не каждая семера может, поэтому и спрашиваю. Убедитесь, что с поддержкой TLS на уровне операционок все ок, в первую очередь - со стороны сервера.

Comment: @aepot Windows Server 2008 R2. Да, я читал, что могут быть из-за этого проблемы. Не подскажешь, как и где можно проверить поддержку? Кстати если зайти на сервер и открыть эту ссылку в браузере, то пдф откроется нормально, так что возможно дело не в операционке.

Comment: Большинство популярных браузеров используют встроенные TLS движки, а не со стороны ОС, так что не показатель.

Comment: @aepot Понял, спасибо. То есть нужно проверить поддержку tls в текущей версии ОС на сервере? Получается, если сделать перенос сервака на Win Server 2012 сервер, то должно все заработать?

Comment: По поводу проверок, полинтернета забито всякими гайдами об этом вопросе. По поводу переноса на более новую ось - да, должно помочь.